# On which bit does the Data field start in a TCP segment?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, http-request

I want to read HTTP requests using sockets on Python. Specifically, the Request Line, General Headers, and Request Headers, based on [this](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_HTTPRequestMessageFormat.htm#Figure_317). To perform this, I need to read the Data field of the TCP segment, but how will I know on which bit the Data field starts on? It would be on a multiple of 32, but would I have to brute force it (i.e. checking if the first 32 bytes look like "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1").

Comment: Are you doing this for educational purposes? If not, consider simply using one of the many HTTP libraries for Python (such as the built-in `urllib`).

Comment: Yes, it's for educational purposes. I just want to see if it can be done with sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a stream socket, Python takes care of the TCP encapsulation/decapsulation for you. Thus, all you have to do is use the socket `recv` function - the first bytes you receive will be `GET` (assuming a well-formed HTTP request).

Answer (score 0):

the TCP header length is variable but it is stated within the TCP header itself.
The first 4 bits of the 13th byte(bits 96 - 99) is the binary representation of the data offset or header size in 32 bit words.

So for example the minimum data offset is 20 bytes so the data offset field in the header will be `0101`. that is 5 32 bit words = 5 * 4 bytes = 20 bytes.

check out the [wikipedia page for TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) for more information